# Delete 100000 records from datastore using java

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Program to delete 100000 records in bulk from datastore using java.Currently i am doing.

```
 public void deleteExistingResults() throws InterruptedException {
      log.info("inside deleteExistingResults");
    ArrayList<Key> keys = new ArrayList<Key>();
    List<Entity> results = getResults();
    for (Entity entity : results) {
      keys.add(entity.getKey());
      }
    log.info("deleteExistingResults:outside loop");
    service.delete(keys);
  }
```

where getResults return all the keys from datastore.I am getting this error.
com.insightsapp.cron.controller.CronTask runTask: Encountered an exception  too much contention on these datastore entities. please try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using something like the [MapReduce library](https://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInJava) or at least using the Task Queue for deleting in batches of hundreds or so.